# visual studio 2012 debugger doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, debugging

My visual studio 2012 had stopped showing debugger exceptions. I mean this dialog that shows me exact exception and line: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC286574.jpg.

In example if I run following code in visual studio:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace debugger_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int zero = 0;
            int a = 1/zero; // it hangs on this line
            MessageBox.Show("this messagebox is never shown");
        }
    }
}
```

then it doesn't return any exception. It just starts and no code after `int a = 1/zero;` is executed.

But when I run the same program alone as a compiled .exe then it returns this kind of exception: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC8596.gif in this case about DivideByZeroException.

- It happens to any project.
- Repairing and reinstalling visual studio didn't resolve it. Although some VS settings were kept after reinstallation.
- I am not aware of any changes that could cause it and I am not sure when it started happening.

How may I get debugger from the first picture working in visual studio again? Thanks.

EDIT: Sascha's advise didn't completely resolve my problem.
I can't figure out how to not throw an exception that is inside try{} code but throw an exception that is not inside try{}.

Following codes either only throw an exception or only hangs on `int gg = 1/a;` line no matter wherher I use try/catch or not.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int zero = 0;
    int a = 1/zero; // this line should throw an exception
    MessageBox.Show("to be never shown");
}
```

__

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int zero = 0;
        int a = 1/zero;
        MessageBox.Show("to be never shown");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("catched"); // it should show this messagebox
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to set it up correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have fixed it for me so far.

- In Registry Editor, locate the following registry subkey: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
- Create a registry entry of the DWORD value.
- Name the new registry entry DisableUserModeCallbackFilter.
- Set the value of the DisableUserModeCallbackFilter registry entry to 1.

found there http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038/en-us

And it has to be compiled as release. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question about a known problem on [x64 systems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/325742/exception-assistant-dialog-box-doesnt-appear-when-debugging-in-vb2008-express):

> This is a known issue on 64-bit OS platform. The reason is that the
>   64bit OS core does not allow user mode exception through kernal mode
>   stacks. The exception is swallowed by OS sliently. That happens in
>   FormLoad handler, because it is called in an OS callback. 32bits OS
>   doesn't do this, so it doesn't repro there.
>
> The OS team is investigating related issues. In the mean time, you do
>   have to work around this issue. Turning on "Stop on first chance
>   exception" will make the debugger to stop in this scenario. But it
>   does make the debugger to stop very often, so you might want to do
>   this only when you find a problem

It's a bug / limitation of Visual Studio that happens when your PC is 64 bit and the exception happens in form load.

Comment: Aha. I got it working by debug, exceptions, check thrown for all, ok. Thanks for pointing me the right direction!